# Html Fixed layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I don't understand why the nav element is aligned to `.main` section element, should the nav not align with the window?

My code is [here](https://codepen.io/xsmyqf/pen/MXQMwW)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 7%;
  background-color: #0aa8d6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: orangered;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<section class="main">
  <aside></aside>
  <section class="content">hello，programmer</section>
</section>
```

Comment: when I set nav with top:0 it is what I want style,but I don't understand the nav is not aligned to window defaultly?

Comment: You have to tell a fixed element **where to be** otherwise it defaults to where it is, - https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#fixed-pos

Comment: See also [collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you added `position:fixed;` to it and didn't say where you wanted it to stay.

> A fixed position element is positioned relative to the viewport, or
>   the browser window itself. The viewport doesn't change when the window
>   is scrolled, so a fixed positioned element will stay right where it is
>   when the page is scrolled, creating an effect a bit like the old
>   school "frames" days.

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 7%;
  background-color: #0aa8d6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

nav { 
  background-color: orangered;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%; 
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<section class="main">
  <aside></aside>
  <section class="content">hello，programmer</section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

This actually has to do with the Types of positioning. You can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

But fixed and absolute position are positioned by the containing block and the is the ancestor relative to which the element is positioned.